# How to set only one object to spawn with a timer?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently a beginner trying to learn programming with as3 so bear with me. I have this code so far and my game repeatedly spawns the Food2 (golden apple) but it does not stop.  **Here is my code so far:**

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    const speed:int = 10;
    var score:int;
    var vx:int;
    var vy:int;
    var gFood:Food;
    var gFood2:Food2;
    var head:SnakePart;
    var SnakeDirection:String;
    var snake:Array;
    var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    var downPressed:Boolean = false;
    var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000,1);

    public function Main(){
        init();
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    function init():void {
        vx = 1; vy = 0;
        score = 0;
        snake = new Array();
        SnakeDirection = "";
        addFood();
        myTimer.start();
        head = new SnakePart();
        head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        snake.push(head);
        addChild(head);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , onKeyUp);
        start1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startgame);
        help1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, helpplayer);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , onKeyDown);
    }
    private function startgame(event:MouseEvent):void {
        gotoAndPlay(3);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);
        stop();
    }
    private function helpplayer(event:MouseEvent):void {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
        stop();
    }
    function addFood():void {
        gFood = new Food();
        gFood.x = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-100);
        gFood.y = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-100);
        addChild(gFood);
    }
    function addFood2():void {
        gFood2 = new Food2();
        gFood2.x = 70 + Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-100);
        gFood2.y = 70 + Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-100);
        addChild(gFood2);
    }
    function reset():void {
        gotoAndStop(1);
        score = 0;
        removeChild(gFood);
        removeChild(gFood2);
        myTimer.stop();
        addFood();
        head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        vx = 1;vy = 0;
        for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
            removeChild(snake[i]);
            snake.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
           SnakeDirection = "left";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
           SnakeDirection = "right";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
            SnakeDirection = "up";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            SnakeDirection = "down";
        }
    }
    function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP ) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }
    }
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
        Timerfood();
        txtScore.text = "Score:" + String(score);
        if(SnakeDirection == "left" && vx != 1) {
            vx = -1;
            vy = 0;
        }
        else if(SnakeDirection == "right" && vx != -1) {
            vx = 1;
            vy = 0;
        }
        else if(SnakeDirection == "up" && vy != 1) {
            vx = 0;
            vy = -1;
        }
        else if(SnakeDirection == "down" && vy != -1) {
            vx = 0;
            vy = 1;
        }
        if(head.x - head.width/2 <= 0){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.x + head.width/2 >= stage.stageWidth){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.y - head.height/2 <= 0){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.y + head.height/2 >= stage.stageHeight){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }

        for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
            snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
            snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
        }
        head.x += vx*speed;
        head.y += vy*speed;

        for(var i = snake.length-1;i>=1;--i){
            if(snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y){
                reset();
                break;
            }
        }
        if(head.hitTestObject(gFood)){
            score += 1;
            removeChild(gFood);
            addFood();
            var bodyPart = new SnakePart();
            bodyPart.x = snake[snake.length - 1].x;
            bodyPart.y = snake[snake.length - 1].y;
            snake.push(bodyPart);
            addChild(bodyPart);
        }
        if(head.hitTestObject(gFood2)){
            score += 2;
            removeChild(gFood2);

            bodyPart = new SnakePart();
            bodyPart.x = snake[snake.length - 1].x;
            bodyPart.y = snake[snake.length - 1].y;
            snake.push(bodyPart);
            addChild(bodyPart);
        }
        function Keyboard_a(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == 82) {
            resetgame();
            }
        }
        function resetgame():void {
            score = 0;
            if (contains(head))
                removeChild(head);
            init();
        }
        }
        function Timerfood():void {
            var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000,1);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
            function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void{
                trace("Timer is Triggered");
                addFood2();
            }
            myTimer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what specific logic you want to implement, but it looks like you need to create an enemy only once. And it looks like the problem is: you call the **Timerfood** method in the **onEnterFrame** listeners, which itself is called many times per second according to the framerate of your app (e.g. 30 times per second).

I would suggest you to remove the call of **Timerfood** from the **onEnterFrame** method, and put it in the end of the **init** method.

Comment: ... Also don't forget to put your `Keyboard_a()`, `resetgame()` and `Timerfood()` functions outside your `onEnterFrame()` one ... (@a-t)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my English is not very good, but I try tell the possible reason,
the method Timerfood() is called on method onEnterFrame(), that initialize myTimer for each frame, so may be the solution is, remove this line into TimerFood() method:

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000,1);

and call TimerFood() only in startgame() method.

I hope you can understand me.